# Is there any way to find out $x! = n$ by hand?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've given myself this question but I can't see how to get it. I'm actually not taking calculus I'm in high school taking Algebra 2 but I've learned a bit or two from this site.

I did:

$x! = 10$

Trying to solve for $x$ but I had trouble doing so. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: There is no integer $x$ whose factorial is $10$. Indeed, since factorials form a strictly increasing sequence and $4!=24$, if 10 were a factorial it would be one of $1!$, $2!$ or $3!$. But it isn't.

Comment: However, one can extend the factorial function to a function of arbitrary reals (or even complex numbers) using the gamma function. There won't be a closed solution to this though (or I'll eat my shoe).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @anon, the chances of *that* being the answer being sought are vanishingly small, don't you think?

Comment: If one can solve $\Gamma(x+1)=10$ *by hand*, I solute him!

Comment: I suspect the question is $10!$, which is not a very difficult mental arithmetic exercise

Comment: @Mariano: Of course. I was just adding commentary.

Comment: Simple: $x = Γ^{-1}(10) - 1$.  The hard part is finding the decimal representation.

Comment: @anon routine calculations show that $z = \frac{9  \pi^2 + 8  \pi - 45}{5 \pi}$ satisfies $\Gamma(z) = 10$. Bon appetit!

Comment: *This question is unclear or not useful*

Comment: @guy: Yeah, as long as $$\Gamma=\frac{50\pi}{9\pi^2+8\pi-45},$$ right? 8-) But I'm keeping my shoe uneaten, thankyouverymuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram alpha gives the roots of $\Gamma(x+1)=10$ as
$-4.995806,
-4.016334,
-2.947296,
-2.097191,
-1.095325,
3.390078.$

One root of $\Gamma(y)=x$ is approximated by $\frac{L(x)}{W(\frac{L(x)}e)}+\frac{1}2$ where $L(x)=\ln(\frac{x+c}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$, $c\approx0.036534$ and $W(x)$ is the principal branch of the inverse of $xe^x$. $W(x)$ can be approximated by selecting an intial $w_0$, and find succesive approximations $w_{j+1}=w_j-\frac{w_je^{w_j}-z}{e^{w_j}+w_je^{w_j}}$. $e^x$ and $\ln {1+x}$ can be found using $1+x+ \frac{x^2}/{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}...$ and $x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+...$ respectively. This can be done by hand but is tedious.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0)

EDIT: The expansion for $\ln(x+1)$ only works if $|x|<1$. Otherwise use $\ln x\approx \frac{\pi}{2M(1,\frac{4}s}-m\ln 2$ with $M(1,\frac{4}s)=$ thearithmetic geometric mean of $1$ and $\frac{4}s$ ,$s=x2^m$ and $m$ any chosen integer (larger $m$ give a closer approximation).

Answer (score 1):

If one function doesn't work, you can always create a new one that does.

Choose a small number, say $d$ ($0\lt d \lt 1$), and define a factorial-like function
$$F(k)=d(d+1)(d+2)\dots(k+d-1)(k+d).$$

After a bit of trial and error, if we take $d=\frac{16}{25} = 0.64$, we find that $F(3) = 0.64 \times 1.64 \times 2.64 \times 3.64 = 10.086$
to five significant digits, which is fairly close to 10. Other values of $d$ may get even closer.
It's not quite factorial, but is in the spirit of factorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a good numerical answer, get a calculator (such as the better HP calculators) that have both the Gamma function and a numeric solver.

Answer (score -3):

If you allow for approximate solutions, in other words, you interpret "=" as meaning "approximately equal to", then you **might** consider 3 as a solution, since 3!=6, and 4!=24.

Comment: Then how about 4!!

Comment: @TheChaz 4 might work also (but I don't see how 4!! will work).  Do you want only an over-approximation, with an over-approximation satisfying (10-x)<0?  Or do you want only an under-approximation with an under-approximation satisfying (10-x)>0?  Do you want both over and under approximations?  Which sort of metric do you think best suited here for determining how close a positive integer lies to n where n!=10 in say this graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Factorial_interpolation.png?

Comment: Oh I don't know. I was thinking of asking you the same question about metrics. Whatever you decide on, it should be that d(4!!, 10) = d(8, 10) < d(3!, 10), d(4!, 10) :)